# Implementing a filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to implement the following filter on a discrete signal `x`:

[image]

I'm supposed to write a MATLAB function that takes a length-M (> N) vector `x` and a scalar N as input. The output should be a length-M vector `y`.

I should then test the filter with M = 50, `x[n]=cos(n*pi/5)+dirac[n-30]-dirac[n-35]` and N = 4, 8, 12.

Here is my try, which returns *Inf* with the given input and `N`:

```
function y = filt( x, N )
% filter function
    if(~isvector(x))
        error('Input must be a vector')
    end
    y = zeros(1,length(x));
    temp = zeros(1,length(x));
    n=1;
    for v = x(:)
        temp(n) = v(n);
        if(n <= N-1)
            y(n) = max(x);
            n = n+1;
        elseif(n >= N-1)
            y(n) = max(temp);
        end
    end
end
```

I also tried using the built-in `filter` function but I can't get it to work.

Code for using the filter:

```
p = zeros(1,50);
for i=0:50
    p(i+1)= cos(i*pi/5)+dirac(i-30)-dirac(i-35)
end
y = filt(p,4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `dirac(0)` gives you `Inf`.  This will happen in two places in your signal, where `n=30` and `n=35`.  I'm assuming you want the **unit impulse** instead.  As such, create a signal where at `n = 31` and `n = 36`, the output is 1, then add this with your cosine signal.  This is because MATLAB starts indexing at 1 and not 0, and so `dirac[0]` would mean that the first point of your signal is non-zero, so translating this over by 30: `dirac[n-30]` would mean that the 31st point is non-zero.  Similar case for `dirac[n-35]`, so the 36th point is non-zero:

```
p = zeros(1,50);
p(31) = 1; p(36) = 1;
p = p + cos((0:49)*pi/5);
y = filt(p,4);
```

---

I also have some reservations with your code.  It doesn't do what you think it's doing.  Specifically, I'm looking at this section:

```
n=1;
for v = x(:)
    temp(n) = v(n);
    if(n <= N-1)
        y(n) = max(x);
        n = n+1;
    elseif(n >= N-1)
        y(n) = max(temp);
    end
end
```

Doing `v = x(:)` would produce a **column** vector, and using a loop with a column vector will have unintentional results.  Specifically, this loop will only execute **once**, with `v` being the entire signal.  You also aren't checking the conditions properly for each window.  You are doing `max(x)`, which applies the maximum **to the entire signal**, and not the window.

---

If I can suggest a rewrite, this is what you should be doing instead:

```
function y = filt( x, N )
% filter function
    if(~isvector(x))
        error('Input must be a vector')
    end
    y = zeros(1,length(x));

    %///// CHANGE
    for n = 1 : numel(x)
        if (n <= N)
            y(n) = max(x(1:n));
        else
            y(n) = max(x(n:-1:n-N+1));
        end    
    end
end
```

---

Take note that the `if` statement is `n <= N`.  This is because in MATLAB, we start indexing at 1, but the notation in your equation starts indexing at 0.  Therefore, instead of checking for `n <= N-1`, it must now be `n <= N`.

Comment: I was thinking about that but the input signal does contain dirac, here's an image: http://i.imgur.com/ZiLO7cG.jpg

Comment: @Lightvvind In DSP, the dirac is the unit impulse.  In continuous-time, the dirac's definition is 0 everywhere except for `t=0`, which in this case is Infinite.

Comment: @Lightvvind no problem.  BTW, there were some problems with your script.  I made a rewrite.  It should now work.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to look at your code. I'm still quite inexperienced in MATLAB.

Comment: @Lightvvind no problem.  Please ask anything about the code that confuses you.  I'm also available in our MATLAB chat room if you'd like to talk: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave